# Controlling gizmo size

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am wondering what defines the size of the section Gizmo, and if there are any way to control this?

I did some experiments in a model by create some section planes on 2 different surfaces (in the same model and session), and ended up with significantly different sized Gizmo. (sections created via the context menu)

[image]

[image]

As you see on the two screenshots from our Forge App, the zoom-in on the two different objects are comparable, but in the first case the arrow is so large that it is basically unusable.

I looked into the section style to see difference, but I am not able to see any difference from in the 2 different sections, so therefor my questions are now:
What defines the size of the Gizmo, and why does it change from object to object?
Are we able to control the size?

Hope someone has some inputs that might help me forward.

File used in example is a DGN file and Viewer is version 7.37.

Thanks in advance!

*EDITS: Photos changed to screenshots from custom forge app instead of BIM360 + added information about viewer version+file extension*

Comment: can you please update your question with: images from your custom ap; viewer version; and model extension/type. thanks

Comment: I updated the question with photos from our custom app and information about viewer version and file.

Comment: thanks, let me check with the Viewer team

Comment: Thanks Augusto! Looking forward to hearing back from you!

Answer (score 0):

The gizmo should have a size relative to the size of your viewer/screen. The image you're showing above is from BIM 360, where you cannot customize it.

Comment: Thanks for comment Augusto. Yes, the picture was from BIM360 since my Forge app was currently not on the newest version of the viewer so I was checking difference.
I made the same tests now on newest version of viewer and seems to still experience the above. To me the gizmo is different sizes when creating a section plane of 2 different objects.
You are saying that we are not able to customize on BIM360. Would I be able to on a custom Forge app?

Comment: Hi Augusto, any response from the Viewer team yet? Thanks a lot!